# Unity(2020.3.11f1) acceder o destruir imagenes de un canvas

Tags: c#, unity

he hecho un juego 2d plataformero comun y el personaje al empezar tiene 3 vidas, esto lo he hecho con un canvas y 3 imagenes de corazones, ya tengo el codigo hecho en el playercontroller para que al hacerme daño me quite 1 vida y funciona, solo necesito saber como puedo destruir una imagen(especificamente acceder a Hearts y luego a una imagen), se que existen 2 metodos, Destroy() y SetActive() pero como accedo al canvas para poder usar uno de esos metodos(los corazones solo son imagenes)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una forma simple de acceder podría ser

```
GameObject.Find("Canvas/Hearts/life1").SetActive(false);
```

También podrías hacer un método para llamarlo más fácil por posición a la hora de ocultar un corazón, algo así:

```
public void HideHeart(int pos)
{
  //obtienes la ruta del object y le añades la posición, luego desactivas o usas Destroy, lo que mejor te venga
  GameObject.Find("Canvas/Hearts/life"+pos).SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

La solución que te propongo se basa en generar una lista de gameObjects con las tres imágenes del Canvas. De esta manera puedes desactivarlos o destruirlos fácilmente con un código similar a:

`myListOfLives[0].SetActive(false);`

Espero haberte ayudado! :)